# MOZILLA_PKIX_ERROR_ADDITIONAL_POLICY_CONSTRAINT_FAILED workaround for intranet

Tags: firefox, security, ssl, certificate

On their help page, under the caption *Bypassing the warning*, Mozzila has the following box:

> **Note:** Some security warnings cannot be bypassed.

This seems to be the case of the certificate that an intranet site uses. I need to access this page to work (it's a bug tracker).

This is the explanation Firefox shows for the error:

> xxxxxxx uses an invalid security certificate.
>
> Certificates issued by GeoTrust, RapidSSL, Symantec, Thawte, and
>   VeriSign are no longer considered safe because these certificate
>   authorities failed to follow security practices in the past.
>
> Error code: MOZILLA_PKIX_ERROR_ADDITIONAL_POLICY_CONSTRAINT_FAILED

I understand the need for this warning, but I do not understand why I cannot bypass it. Without it, I can't work.

Is there a hidden setting to ignore any certificate error?

Answer (score 1):

In the address bar, type `about:config`.  Heed the warning about dragons.  In the search box enter `security.pki.distrust_ca_policy`.  Change the value to `0` to allow these certificates.

Remember though that there's a [valid reason](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mozilla.dev.security.policy/FLHRT79e3XE/discussion) that browsers block these certificates, so only do this if you understand the risk.

Note that Mozilla have stated that this option will be removed in version 65 of Firefox.

Comment: The option is still there in Firefox 73,and works!